# PHP \ MySQL comparison of characters per line and output

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Problem. I have a database with numbers.

```
    [1] 11122111
    [2] 11133111
    [3] 11144111
    [4] 11156111

    [5] 11133789
    [6] 11133987

    [7] 45634111
    [8] 09274111
```

I want to compare them to the first 4-5 characters, and if the result of a match to show it. For example, to [1] 11122111 , [2] 11133111 , [3] 11144111 and [4] 11156111 display the result  111-xx-xxx. to [5] 11133789 and [6] 11133987 results 111-33-xxx.
I've tried a lot but the desired results have not yet been received.

**I have realized that it is not properly raised the issue. Thank you for your answers led to the desired solution.
The result is this:**

```
$phptrn = array();
foreach($patresult as $ptrn) {
$phptrn[] = substr($ptrn['phone'], 0, 4).'****';
$phptrn[] = substr($ptrn['phone'], 0, 5).'***';
}
$phptrn = array_unique($phptrn);
foreach($phptrn as $phpat){.....
```

Comment: They are stored as strings, and get them I can from the database. I can not handle the array to compare and output values.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you actually tried this, it isn't that hard to find....

```
$find = '11133';

$d = [
    '11122111',
    '11133111',
    '11144111',
    '11156111',
    '11133789',
    '11133987',
    '45634111',
    '09274111'
];

foreach($d as $item){
    if(strpos($item, $find)!==FALSE){
        echo $item ."<br />";
    }
}
```

Just supply the `$find` with the characters you want to search. Alternatively you could use `substr($STRING, 0, 4);` to get the first 5 letters of your chosen string.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a SQL approach to this problem. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b9641/9/0

It uses a table of the integers from 8 .. 1, computes the prefix, then counts identical prefixes.

Here's the query.  That joined table is the integers.

```
select n, Rpad(left(val, n),8,'X') AS prefix, count(*) as count
  from t
  join (SELECT 8 AS n UNION ALL 
        SELECT 7 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 6 UNION ALL
        SELECT 5 UNION ALL
        SELECT 4 UNION ALL
        SELECT 3 UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 UNION ALL
        SELECT 1)
      AS n
   GROUP BY N, Rpad(left(val, n),8,'X')
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, n DESC
```

Here's the result set.  I think this is the sort of thing you're looking for. It should get you started at any rate.

```
| N |   PREFIX | COUNT |
|---|----------|-------|
| 3 | 111XXXXX |     6 |
| 2 | 11XXXXXX |     6 |
| 1 | 1XXXXXXX |     6 |
| 5 | 11133XXX |     3 |
| 4 | 1113XXXX |     3 |
```

Comment: Big +1 from me, now that's a completely different alternative! Learning stuff everyday :D